# Does this graph of non-coprime pairs of numbers have any interesting properties?

Tags: graphing-functions, relations, integers, coprime

[image: On this graph, I drew 1*1 squares centered on points %(a,b)% if %a% and %b% were non-coprime]
I guess it looks nice but aside from that what else could I say about this graph? What sorts of statements about this could I make and try to prove? ...Later, I will try coloring based on the g.c.f. of each pair, i.e. if it were 2 I would use blue, if it were 3 red, etc.

Lastly... if this already exists somewhere and has been studied already, where could I read further about it?